# How to align a paragraph to center of cell in table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want the paragraph in the second row to be aligned to center of table. How can I do that?

[Full HTML & CSS code in this link](http://jsfiddle.net/MqgYw/)

CSS:

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
table, td {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border:1px solid black;
    padding:0px 5px 10px;
}
.separate {
    text-align:center;
}
.separate p{
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    width:50%;
}
```

table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>AAA</td>
        <td>BBB</td>
        <td>CCC</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" class="separate" >
            <p>paragrap</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the p left and right margin auto margins.

```
.separate p{
    border:1px solid lightgray;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;
}
```

Comment: Great, ambuletz! Thank you so much!